# Flex & SVN - what to ignore?

Tags: apache-flex, svn

I want to version control my Flex application with SVN. What should I include and what should I ignore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm only ignoring the `.settings` directory.

You should view the source of the project files (`.actionScriptProperties`, `.flexProperties`, `.project`) and decide whether you or your team need their settings on a clean checkout or not.

If you put these files under version control, then you should avoid workstation specific directories in your settings (Flex Server Settings) and substitute them with [*path variables*](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cpathvars.htm).

This for example is the content of my `.flexProperties` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<flexProperties 
    enableServiceManager="false" flexServerFeatures="4" flexServerType="2" 
    serverContextRoot="/myProject" 
    serverRoot="${HTTP_DOCS}/myProject/" 
    serverRootURL="http://localhost/myProject" 
    toolCompile="true" useServerFlexSDK="false" version="1"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Agree. bin-debug and bin-release are the first ones to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you can ignore:

- .settings
- .FlexUnitSettings
- html-template (could be generated)
- .actionScriptProperties
- .flexProject
- .project
- .sourceMate (or whatever plugin you have)

Comment: You can't ignore .flexProject, .project and .actionScriptProperties, these are project settings. You can ignore bin-debug and bin-release to avoid litter repository.

Comment: you can ignore these settings but it's your decision. If another developer has another project configuration it will overwrite your config every time he pushs something. bin-debug and bin-release is a good point. I don't listed them as they are note in my project folders.

Comment: Different config are problematic indeed. But if you don't commit these settings at all, project can't be built after checkout from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I actually keep everything other than source code out of SVN.

My project in FB thats linked to SVN has no project information attached at all (It's just a project), I have a second project that I keep locally which IS a Flex / AIR project which just links to the source in my controlled project.

Not only does this mean I don't run the risk of checking in generated files, .* files, etc. It means I can keep a different set up from other members in my team.

Comment: I use a similar approach, except I don't use two projects. I use a linked directory in one project and set that as the primary source directory; which is under source control.

Comment: The only real reason for keeping it as a project is because we use Jupiter for our code reviews which means it needs to be a project. Jupiter's output gets stored in SVN, so it was a little white lie in my answer. If it wasn't for Jupiter, it wouldn't be a project at all.